# How to find the common elements inside two list of values of dictionary in Python without using sets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
dmarks={'A': [100,127, 130, 123, 210], 'B': [127, 130, 123, 210, 109]}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether this helps :

```
dmarks={'A': [100,127, 130, 123, 210], 'B': [127, 130, 123, 210, 109]}
a,b,c=dmarks['A'],dmarks['B'],[]
for i in a:
    if i in b:
        c.append(i)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can not use sets I suggest iterating through the list.

```
dmarks={'A': [100,127, 130, 123, 210], 'B': [127, 130, 123, 210, 109,]}


def find_common(a,b): 
    return [value for value in a if value in b] 

results = find_common(dmarks['A'], dmarks['B'])
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
res = [a for a in dmarks['A'] if (a in dmarks['A']) and (a in dmarks['B'])]
```

---

```
# [127, 130, 123, 210]
```